# Polymer AngularJS not validating input field correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, polymer

I'm having the following code in an AngularJS + Polymer application:

```html
<p>This is the profile view.</p>

<form novalidate>
    <paper-input-decorator label="First name" floatingLabel error="First name is required!" autoValidate>
        <input id="form_firstName" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" is="core-input" required>
    </paper-input-decorator>
</form>
```

Resulting in:
[image]

As you can see text is being set by Angular over the directive 'ng-model="user.firstName'. But the input field gives an error about text being required. When I set the cursor to the input field and add or remove a single letter, this gets validated correctly. I tried adding an id to the 'paper-input-decorator' / 'input', and calling 'validate()' but this does not work.

```html
<p>This is the profile view.</p>

<form novalidate>
    <paper-input-decorator label="First name" floatingLabel error="First name is required!" autoValidate>
        <input id="form_firstName" type="text" ng-model="user.firstName" is="core-input" required>
    </paper-input-decorator>
</form>

<script>
document.getElementById("form_firstName").addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log("Fire!")
    $('#form_firstName').validate();
});
</script>
```

How should I solve this problem? I need to validate the Polymer input field on the moment Angular sets it's value.

Comment: It's my knowledge that Angular and Polymer dont go along very well, because of how they both use expressions very similarly.

Comment: I think I need to try to find a way to bind user.firstName from Angular with user.firstName from Polymer. Gave ng-polymer-element a try but no succes so far